# Confusing about set dependencies to component interface in dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

In general, in a component interface, we set...

```
@Component(dependencies = xxxComponent.class)
```

...it means that component `A` depends on component `B`.

But if we set it like...

```
@Component(dependencies = xxxModule.class)
```

..is it the same to set it like the following?

```
@Component(modules = xxxModule.class)
```

If it is different, what is the difference between these two ways?

the code is like this:

Component interface:
[image]

The Module :
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Setting `@Component(dependencies=...)` sets [*Component Dependencies*](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies). A component can not be dependent on a module, but only on other components. I'm not sure if (or why) this would even compile if you were to add a *module* to the list of *component* dependencies.

A component consist of multiple modules, which is why the `@Component(modules=...)` syntax is needed. It lets you declare the modules *used* by this component. This is the right way to add your modules your componend needs.

So if you depend on another *component*, use `dependencies=Component`, but if you work with modules just properly declare them as modules. Those 2 attributes for sure are not the same.

Comment: Hi, David, I am reading others' code  and i upload the images about the code details, it surely runs well, but i  don't know why...